# Php Console, unable connect to .wsdl with soap

Tags: php, openssl

I have a code with Yii, that consume a webservice, and when I try connect to the webservice, I got a error:

> Handler captured error 2: 'SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
> error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed'
> Handler captured error 2: 'SoapClient::SoapClient(): Failed to enable crypto'
> Handler captured error 2: 'SoapClient::SoapClient(https://cel.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantesOffline?wsdl): failed to open stream: operation failed'
> Handler captured error 2: 'SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://cel.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantesOffline?wsdl"'
> Error en la Conexión al SRI (Validación), no hay servicio disponible

I try with PHP 7.4, 8.1 and 8.2, but i got the same error. The webservice is online and I have enable the modules openssl and soap in my php.ini

Comment: Probable [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65442972/ssl-routinestls-process-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL routines:tls\_process\_server\_certificate:certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65442972/ssl-routinestls-process-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed)

Comment: No, my code is good, because that run an another sites and I don't have any problems, I think the problem is with internet conecction, probably the router or the isp. Now, we are testing with other isp.